# duda sobre promises Javascript

Tags: javascript, promesas

```
function promise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            JSON.parse('ok'); //disparando excepción
        },100);
    });
}

promise()
    .then(null,function(error){
        alert('entrando a onRejected');
        alert(error);
        throw new Error('¿catch me atrapas?');
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        alert('entrando a catch');
        alert(error);
    });`
```

básicamente creía que cuando ocurría un error o una excepción durante la ejecución de la promesa era "capturado" en el segundo parámetro de del método "then" o en el "catch".

pero en este caso al ocurrir una excepción dentro del "setTimeout" por alguna razón no se completa la ejecución de la promesa, es mas nunca llega a ejecutarse "then" ni "catch". si elimino el "setTimeout" el error si que es capturado en "then", es como si no se propagara el error dentro de "setTimeout" a la promesa y luego a "onRejected".

¿como puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que usar `resolve(...)` y `reject(...)` para indicar si hubo algún error en la promesa. El método `then` contiene el código que quieres correr cuando no hubo problemas en la promesa.

```
function promise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            try{
                JSON.parse('ok'); //disparando excepción
                resolve("bueno"); // resolve() si no hay problemas
            }
            catch(ex){
                reject("malo");  // reject() si hay problemas
            }
        },100);
    });
}
promise()
    .then(function(resultado){
        alert('Sin problemas');
        alert(resultado);
        throw new Error('¿catch me atrapas?');
    }) 
    .catch(function(error){
        alert('entrando a catch');
        alert(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Las promesas no manejan excepciones por si solas, debes incluir un try catch en el cuerpo de la promesa que cuando detecte un error se pase como parámetro al callback reject. El método then es la acción que se debe ejecutar cuando la promesa se haya cumplido y el método catch se ejecuta cuando se produjo algún error. Los valores que retornen los métodos then y catch son los mismos que le pases a los callback resolve y reject correspondientemente.

```js
function promise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
          try {
            let result = JSON.parse('ok') //disparando excepción
            resolve(result)
          } catch(e) {
            reject(e)                      
          }
      },100);
   })
}

promise()
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result)
     })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log('Se produjo un error' + error)
    });
```